# Reevaluate included partial on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do a custom menu which looks similar to the dropdown list, but also i'd like it to be dependant on the current value, e.g i have three modules: `["A", "B", "C"]` and a respective partial which builds a `<ul>` with `ngRepeat` and this partial is included into my html with `ngInclude` directive. So when i click on the menu, i see the list in which the first item is the current page, then i choose module "B" and i want to see the items in a different order, i.e `["B", "A", "C"]`.

In the code it looks like this:

My include directive -

```
<ng-include src="'assets/app/modules/header/header-menu.html'"></ng-include>
```

Which loads this partial:

```
<ul id="header-navigation"
    class="header-navigation"
    data-ng-hide="headerVm.showMenu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="module in headerVm.modules"
        class="header-title noselect">
        <span data-ng-click="headerVm.open(module)">{{ module }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I guess i need some advanced stuff like `$eval` to show the reordered menu list on each click or there are some better technics to do this?

**Update**

To update the list of modules i have this:

```
function HeaderController(routehelper) {
    var self = this
    self.showMenu = false;
    self.showAppMenu = function() {
        self.showMenu = !self.showMenu;
    };
    self.open = function(module) {
        self.current = module;
        rebuildMenu(module, self.modules);
        self.showMenu = true;
    }
}

function rebuildMenu(newModule, modules) {
    var updated = _.without(modules, _.findWhere(modules, newModule));
    updated.unshift(newModule)
}
```

But when angular runs `open` function, the elements are still in the same order, nothing has changed.

Comment: You switch pages, meaning you switch states and switching controllers right ?

Comment: @OmriAharon no, i'm not switching anything, in this part (partial) i just want to show a small menu in which the first item depends on the current value, i can reorder this in javascript, but how can i reevaluate the `ng-repeat` in partial so i could also show the reordered menu?

Comment: So you want the item that you click on the move to top ? Editing the array will make angular to reevaluate your `modules` and it should reflect automatically.

Comment: @OmriAharon correct, i've updated my code, not very comfortable with JS mutable operations, so maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Can you show what `.without(modules, _.findWhere(modules, newModule));` does ?

Comment: @OmriAharon These are from underscore.js, remove current module from the list and put it on top - [without](http://underscorejs.org/#without), [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere)

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is after reading the documentation. `_.without` returns a *copy*, so the actual object on your scope does not get updated.

Comment: How about `self.modules = updated.unshift(newModule)` as your final line ?

Comment: @OmriAharon Yes, though i had another error, but that was my fault, if you can write a minimal answer, i can mark that as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.without` returns a copy, so the actual object on your scope does not get updated.

Use `self.modules = updated.unshift(newModule)`.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure thats is that what You exactly need, but seems you ned something like that:

```
ng-click="headerVm.open(module) ; reverse=!reverse; order('module', reverse)";
```

and in controller that:

```
var orderByFUNC = $filter('orderBy'); 
$scope.order = function(column, reverse) {
    $scope.friends = orderByFUNC($scope.friends , column, reverse);
};
```

here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MKuriata/9m3z14tL/1/

Comment: I've updated my question, your code is similar to what i have, so i guess it should work in my case, maybe with my update it would be clear what i'm doing wrong